# Readthedocs build gives AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: read-the-docs

When I try to build the docs of a project (https://github.com/devolksbank/dvb.datascience/tree/master/docs), I get the following error:

> python3.6 -mvirtualenv --no-site-packages --no-download
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/dvbdatascience/envs/latest
>   Using base prefix '/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2' New python
>   executable in
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/dvbdatascience/envs/latest/bin/python3.6
>   Not overwriting existing python script
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/dvbdatascience/envs/latest/bin/python
>   (you must use
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/dvbdatascience/envs/latest/bin/python3.6)
>   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...   Complete output from command
>   /home/docs/checkouts...latest/bin/python3.6 - setuptools pip wheel:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 8, in
>      File "", line 961, in
>   _find_and_load   File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
>   616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/**init**.py",
>   line 43, in    File "", line 961,
>   in _find_and_load   File "", line 950, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
>   616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 27, in    File "", line 961,
>   in _find_and_load   File "", line 950, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
>   616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3018, in    File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3004, in _call_aside   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2578, in activate   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2152, in declare_namespace   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2092, in _handle_ns   File
>   "/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path AttributeError: '_NamespacePath'
>   object has no attribute 'sort'

How can I solve this?

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was a wrong combination of rtd settings and the .readthedocs.yml file. See https://github.com/devolksbank/dvb.datascience/blob/master/.readthedocs.yml for the working yml file.